# Unable to send photo using Form Submit

Tags: node.js

I've a photo and a paid upload service : http://example.com/in.php .

I'm not able to upload a given jpeg file using this code. It is telling me that **invalid file format** uploaded. But using `file` linux command I can see it is JPEG format. Is there any problem in this code?

```
    fs.readFile('/tmp/photo.jpg'', 'utf8', function(err, contents) {

    var b64 = new Buffer(contents);

    var s = b64.toString('base64');


    var request = require('request')
    request.post('http://example.com/in.php', {
      form: {
        method:'base64',
        key:'cplbhvnmvdn4bjxxchzgqyjz7rf9fy8w',
        body:s,
      }
    }, function (err, res, body) {
      console.log("body=",body);

            console.log("res=",res);

    })

   });
```

Comment: You try using different node modules available on npm  , such as ```Multer``` or ```Formidable```.
They easily parse the file data

Answer (score 0):

I see no mistakes in your process of converting jpeg to base64. However, I would suggest a workaround to use a small [image-to-base64 node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-to-base64).

Also, there's a higher chance of something being wrong in the post request, maybe the upload service API is not accepting the base64 format, maybe the API key is not authorized. Please read their API docs carefully and do as it says & also console log the error code you are receiving.

After all, try something like this with [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

`const image2base64 = require('image-to-base64');
image2base64("path/to/file.jpg") // you can also to use url
    .then(
        (response) => {
            console.log(response); //cGF0aC90by9maWxlLmpwZw==
            axios.post('http://example.com/in.php', base64, {
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                },
              }).then((response) => {
                  console.log(response)
              }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error in uploading.");
              });
            },
        }
    )
    .catch(
        (error) => {
            console.log(error); //Exepection error....
        }
    )`